# I want to execute this bash script but failed

Tags: bash, shell-script, ufw

This script is used to adding new `ufw` rules with the container name without re-typing the container name again. It uses `grep` to get container name.

This is the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "\e[92m[Docker-compose] Deleting old ufw rules...\e[0m"
sudo ufw-docker delete allow ${grep container_name: ./docker-compose.yml | awk '{print $2}'}
echo -e "\e[92m[Docker-compose] Successfully deleting old ufw rules.\e[0m"
sleep 3
echo -e "\e[92m[Docker-compose] Adding new ufw rules...\e[0m"
sudo ufw-docker allow ${grep container_name: ./docker-compose.yml | awk '{print $2}'}
echo -e "\e[92m[Docker-compose] Successfully adding new ufw rules.\e[0m"
```

What's the right way to execute this bash script?

Comment: Where did you get the command? What is it supposed to do? What have you done so far, that you ended up with this? Doesn't seem like a valid meaningful command...

Comment: extract the individual commands and pipelines, and run them on their own. Are you happy with the results? Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: Well, the command for getting container name is `${grep container_name: ./docker-compose.yml | awk '{print $2}'}` Does it work by itself? e. g. `echo ${grep container_name: ./docker-compose.yml | awk '{print $2}'}`

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you mean. You say that you failed? How did you fail? Was there an error message? Or did it just not run? [Edit] your question and provide more details.

Answer (score 3):

Where did you get that script from?  Why does it appear to be attempting [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution) with `${ ... }` (which will just get a "bad substitution" error from bash) instead of `$( ... )`.  Try it with:

```
$(grep container_name: ./docker-compose.yml | awk '{print $2}')
```

Also, you don't need `grep` when you're using `awk` (awk can do its own regex matching). That would be better written as:

```
$(awk '/container_name:/ { print $2 }' ./docker-compose.yml)
```

Answer (score 0):

To run the script, either:

- Set the file's execute permissions:

  ```
  chmod 755 <filename>
  ```

  and then run it

  ```
  ./<filename>
  ```
- Call it using as an argument to `bash`, no need to set the permissions first:

  ```
   bash <filename>
  ```

  To see each line execute, use `-x`

  ```
   bash -x <filename>
  ```